# How do you live-migrate Hyper-V to Azure?

Tags: azure, hyper-v-server-2012, live-migration

I have a new install of Windows Server 2012 with the Hyper-V role setup and a couple VMs running along fat, dumb, and happy. I want to play with Azure hosting for VMs for a couple of stand-alone boxes. Is there anything special that I need to wire up to be able to live-migrate to Azure? I have the 90-day Azure trial account right now. Any special plumbing required? I have not found a lot of documentation about this yet. Everything I found points to manually copying the VHDs via command line and the Azure 2012 SDK.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm pretty sure that LiveMigration requires shared storage so unless your local Hyper-V server is sharing the same storage device with your Azure trial I don't see how this would be possible... but I'm curious to see what answers are illicited.

Comment: I thought that was Microsoft's Big new Thing (tm) with being able to live-migrate without shared storage as long as the Hyper-V host was Server 2012. In one of the Server 2012 Launch videos they showed migration to Azure but never touched on the plumbing to make it work.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe it is possible in Server 2012.

Comment: Shared nothing live migrations do work within Hyper-V environments in the same AD. Azure does run Hyper-V on the back end, but those nodes are not joined to your AD so you cannot live migrate to them.

Answer (score 6):

There is no path to live migrate a VM to Windows Azure. Moving a VM to Azure requires shutting down the VM.